# What is this missile extended beneath an F-104 Starfighter?

Tags: feature-identification, missiles, f-104

On a [video posted on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCYcVQ4dc-M&t=140s) there is a short clip of some sort of rocket-powered device - presumably a missile - extended beneath an [F-104](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter) on a mechanical sling. It must have been lowered into position, since the F-104 certainly couldn't take off with it in place.

I can't find any reference to it, and would like to know what it is.

[image: F-104]
[image: F-104]
device in place and ignition [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCYcVQ4dc-M&t=140s)

Comment: Supersonic store separation is a tricky issue. Using a trapeze makes it much more controlled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extending trapeze launcher was used with the Genie air to air nuclear missile on early star fighters. A similar design was use with F106 delta dart which had an internal missile bay.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter

Comment: There was a nuclear A2A missile? Was it in regular service?

Comment: @CptReynolds It was designed to attack large bomber formations and was fired once in an exercise, with Air Force observers right below the nuclear explosion.

Comment: I was stationed at Griffiss AFB in NY. we had a F106 fighter squadron located with us, the 49th FIS. They kept a pair of aircraft on alert fueled and weapons on board. Of course the USAF will neither confirm nor deny the presence of nuclear weapons on any base. I worked maintenance on the SAC side with B52G and KC135A aircraft. We also had aircraft on alert.